# Enviar string desde una app android a otra app android 2023

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

Debo poder desde una app android nativa, enviar a otra app nativa un string, he usado

```java
ComponentName name = new ComponentName(applicationId,
    "com.example.recibir");
// Create an Intent to start SecondActivity

Intent askIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
askIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
askIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
askIntent.setComponent(name);

//startActivity(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(applicationId));
askIntent.putExtra("resultado", DatosIntegrado.toString());
setResult(2);
startActivityForResult(askIntent, RESULT_OK);
//setResult(2, null);
//startActivity(askIntent);
//activityResultLaunch.launch(askIntent);
```

para poder enviarlo y logro abrir a la app que apunto, pero no logro ver como recibir el string en la app que ya abrio con el codigo, si me pueden ayudar y orientar, estare agradecido

Comment: Probablemente tengas que recuperar la información desde un `intent` [como harías con 2 activities en una misma aplicación](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity?hl=es-419#DisplayMessage).

Answer (score 1):

El constructor de la clase [ComponentName](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName) indica que debes definir el "package name" y la "clase" que deseas abrir:

```
ComponentName(String package name, String clase)
```

Por ejemplo si tu application Id o package name es:

> "com.example.recibir"

y la Activity que deseas abrir es:

> "MainActivity"

Debes definir `ComponentName`  de la siguiente forma:

```
 ComponentName name = new ComponentName("com.example.recibir",
                    "com.example.recibir.MainActivity");
```